# MySQL WorkBench: export data by parts

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like to export just the first 1.000.000 rows from a table in a mysql database.
Based on this answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61805/make-mysql-dump-from-parts-of-each-table#answer-61807
it is possible to specify a `--where` option so that i can filter the exported data.

I just don't understand where should i specify such option in the mysqlworkbench GUI. This is the advanced option page that i can set:
[image]

As you can image, since the database is on a remote host, it would be impractical to connect to it and execute the mysql dump from there.

Comment: So use the command line like the example you quote

Comment: that's a solution, but of course not the most practical one, since the database is on a different network, behind a bastion host. I think that exporting data by parts might be somehow implemented, being a reasonably common task

Comment: Then write a query to select only `1,000,000` rows `LIMIT 1000000` and click the write result to file button menu

Comment: you need to use mysqdump for that